# Проблема с парсингом русских букв в Android

Tags: xml, android, кодировка, java

Есть xml. Его парсю через андройд апликэйшн. Всё получается, если английский язык. Но если поменять в xml - на русский язык, то при отображении страницы в android api - символы отображаются некорректно. Испробовал поменять кодировку в xml  с utf-8 на windows-1251. Не помогло. Пробовал заставить апликацию понимать кодировку -

```
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
is.setEncoding ("windows-1251");    
doc = db.parse(is);
```

Ничего не выходит. Может, кто сможет подсказать. Если надо больше исходника - выложу...

```
is.setEncoding("UTF_8");
```

тоже ничего не выходит

Посмотрел в вики: [кракозябры](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B). 
Сравнил кракозябры. Если мы ставим в xml, который парсим, кодировку 1251, то крокозябры как будто идёт перекодировка из 1251 в 1252. Если мы ставим в xml кодировку utf-8, то крокозябры выглядят, как будто перекодируем из utf в 1252. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
 HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
 line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
```

Это ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте кодировку самого XML файла, он должен быть в UTF-8. Android по умолчанию использует кодировку UTF-8, так что данные должны лежать в UTF-8, а иначе надо перекодировать.

Comment: Т.е. вы про тот вариант, который я уже использовал? Указать в xml кодировку utf-8, а андроид по умолчанию использует utf - 8... так я писал, что выводит абракадабру...
Я аж подумал было, что utf-8 - стандартная кодировка) 
Какие ещё могут быть варианты?

Comment: Из текста вопроса: "Испробовал поменять кодировку в xml с utf-8 на windows-1251."...Т.е. кодировку utf-8  я уже испробовал.

Comment: [link text][1], кодировка самого файла должна быть UTF-8. Если вы создавали свой файл средствами винды, то логично, что у него кодировка - cp1251, а в заголовке вы указываете UTF-8 - вот и получаются кривозябы. Создайте файл Еклипсом (или что вы используете для разработки под андроид), либо перекодируйте. Где-то тут недавно обсуждался вопрос перекодировки под виндами.

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/1414/aleksey-makas

Comment: спасибо,вечером испрбую,через еклипс

Comment: notepad++ вам в помощь.

Comment: Да, млин Intellij IDEA все прекрасно поддерживает...

Comment: такс...так я эту ситуацию делал ещё вчера...
прописывал в самом xml кодировку utf-8 + сохранял в этой кодировке....
не помогает это(((