# Русские символы

Tags: android, кодировка, java

От сервера приходит ответ `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Я его парсю, результат парсинга вывожу в `TextView`. Русские буквы отображаются вот так:

[image]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с парсингом русских букв в Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/94248/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2-%d0%b2-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нашел ответ:

[Проблема с парсингом русских букв в Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/94248/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2-%D0%B2-android)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать конструктор `String(byte[] data, String charsetName)`, в качестве data используйте контент вашего XML файла, ну а потом можно парсить.

Comment: Пробовал, все кодировки перебрал, не получилось!